# Windows 10 Assigned Access (Kiosk Mode) Tablet Mode, without Keyboard

Tags: uwp, tablet, kiosk, kiosk-mode

I'm setting up an app in Assigned Access, which seems to be great alternative for Kiosk with replacing shell. I have some questions...

1. Can I have Navigationbuttons inside my app running in Assigned
   Access? (default Back-Button is not visible)
2. Is it possible to use Assigned Access without Keyboard, running in
   Tablet Mode and showing the Touch-Keyboard automatically, when
   neccessary?
3. If yes: How can I exit without keyboard? (the usual way is to press
   CTRL+ALT+DEL to log out)

I have the tablet mode enabled and I tried setting the registry value for automatically showing touch keyboard 
(`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\TabletTip\1.7\EnableDesktopModeAutoInvoke`).

Answer (score 0):

I surely can answer point 2:
yes. Just enable tablet mode for your local user (domain users cannot start in "assigned access"). Then the virtual keyboard will appear if needed. My experience is, that tablet mode cannot be enabled, when you have multiple monitors. If you have, deaktivate or disconnect them.

point 1:
as long as the navigation buttons only navigate inside your navigation there shouldn't be any problem.

point 3:
we use a USB Keyboard to do so.

Hopefully I provided some useful information for you.

Regards!
Alex

Comment: Sorry, but does not work for me. I have a device for testing (only 1 monitor with touch) and I have tablet mode enabled. But the virtual keyboard does not show up in assigned access. In my app I show a webview, maybe it doesn't recognize the textboxes inside webview, could that be the problem?

Comment: You could verify this with browse website with Edge browser.

Comment: just as extra info. You can use a domain user in the kiosk mode.  You can use the ShellLauncher and under userspecific settings you can add domainuserspecificsettings. I have configured a lot of kiosks like that. (also for me the keyboard on tablet also appreas when needed when the device is in tablet mode)

Answer (score 0):

I have used another method that works fine for me.

Steps I have followed :
1 - Install the last version of Windows 10 21h2 on the kiosk.
2 - Create a local account named kiosk (without password in my case but you can put a password)
3 - Log in into the kiosk account. And activate the **onScreen Keyboard** when no physical keyboard is present.

Here is the checkbox you need to activate :
[1]: https://ibb.co/p3144sK
[2]: https://ibb.co/qMY37DH

4 - Create a assigned access for the existing kiosk user.
5 - reboot

Enjoy.